# Problem about subsets of $\{1, 2,\dots,n\}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Let $A=\{1, 2,\dots,n\}$
What is the maximum possible number of subsets of $A$ with the property that any two of them have exactly one element in common ?

I strongly suspect the answer is $n$, but can't prove it.

Comment: I think answer should be n but i m not sure

Comment: Well, {1}, {1,2}, {1,3}....{1,n} form such a collection of n subsets. The subsets don't have to have the same cardinality.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that simultaneously with your correction, @Cosmonut :)

Comment: I would like to point out that most of the answers are missing the case $\{1, 2\}, \{2, 3\}, \{3, 1\} $, so there is an error in their logic.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, or the finite projective plane with order $n=q^2+q+1$ points and $n$ lines each having $q+1$ points, when $q$ is a prime power. So we can get such a design with arbitrarily large sets.

Comment: @CalvinLin: What happens when $n=4$ ? How do you make such sets?

Comment: @Inceptio No, but as Thomas mentioned, you can for $n  = 13$. I.e. the projective plane of order 3.

Comment: @CalvinLin: $7$ is possible too. Maximum number of subsets is **n**. Right?! Even if you take such cases.!

Comment: Yes, but all the answers try to prove that no such case works with the subsets greater than $2$, and there are such cases. In other words, they are asserting that the simple $\{1\},\{1,2\},\dots,\{1,n\}$ answer is somehow the only representative. I suspect the statement is true, but not by the means that anybody has used to try to prove it. @Inceptio

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: But you can take any element $k$ as common. $\{k\},\{k,2\},\dots,\{k,n\}$. If we take more than $2$ element subsets in this form, number of sets get lowered(Except in your case).

Comment: Why can you take that? There nothing in the condition that requires that the element in every intersection is the same singleton. So all you've shown is that in that very specific case, you can't have more than $n$ such sets. That doesn't resolve the bigger question. @Inceptio

Comment: If the proposition is true, by the Hall's marriage theorem, it is easy to show that there is a system of distinct representatives of any such collection of sets. Basically, you want to show that if $A_1,\dots,A_m$ have the above intersection property, then $|\cup A_i|\geq m$. If the proposition is true, then it is true any subset of the $A_i$ and therefore the $A_i$ satisfy the marriage theorem condition.

Comment: Yes, but nothing about $L$ affected $A_2\cap A_3$, @wece

Comment: I can undelete my answer so you guys can read my starting ideas, if you'd like.

Comment: That $L$ is all of the set, essentially, @wece.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I would like to see your deleted answer.

Comment: @Thomas I've undeleted it.

Comment: I think Sean wins :) I still wish we could find a more direct counting argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a well known type of problem in combinatorics. (Try googling "exact intersections".) The (slight) generalisation of your claim, in which we require $|A\cap B|=\ell>0$ whenever $A\neq B$, is apparently due to Fisher.

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a family of subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ such that for every two distinct $A,B\in\mathcal{A}$ we have $|A\cap B|=\ell$. We claim $|\mathcal{A}|\leq n$. Certainly we're done if some $A\in\mathcal{A}$ has size $\ell$ (this is where we use $\ell>0$), so assume otherwise.

For each $A\in\mathcal{A}$ consider the "indicator vector" $1_A\in\mathbf{R}^n$ given by $1_A(x)=1$ if $x\in A$ and $0$ otherwise. I claim that $\{1_A : A\in\mathcal{A}\}$ is a linearly independent set, so $|\mathcal{A}|\leq n$.

Suppose $\lambda_A\in\mathbf{R}$ are some coefficients such that

$$\sum_{A\in\mathcal{A}} \lambda_A 1_A = 0.$$

Taking the scalar product with $1_B$, noting $1_A\cdot 1_B = \ell$ when $A\neq B$, we have

$$\lambda_B |B| + \sum_{A\neq B} \lambda_A \ell = 0.$$

Rearranging slightly,

$$\lambda_B (|B| - \ell) = - \ell\sum_{A\in\mathcal{A}} \lambda_A.$$

Conclusion: either $\sum\lambda_A = 0$, in which case every $\lambda_B=0$ (since $|B|>\ell$ for all $B\in\mathcal{A}$), or $\sum\lambda_A\neq 0$, in which case all $\lambda_B$ are nonzero and opposite in sign to $\sum\lambda_A$, impossible.

Comment: Yes, I mean the {scalar,dot,inner,...}-product.

Comment: Wait, $\lambda_B$ are not all equal, but rather $\lambda_B=\frac{1}{|B|-\ell}C$? If all the $|B|$ are equal, clearly it is true that the $\lambda_B$ are equal, but we can't conclude that here, can we?

Comment: Ah, thanks, correcting now.

Comment: What we really know is that they are all the same sign, since $|B|>\ell$, which is enough.

Comment: nice proof ....

Comment: Yes, very clever to jump to vector spaces.

Comment: An extremely similar approach is to define the $n\times|\mathcal{A}|$ matrix $M$ by $M_{xA} = 1$ if $x\in A$, $0$ otherwise. Compute the $|\mathcal{A}|\times|\mathcal{A}|$ matrix $M^TM$, notice its particularly simple form, observe that it is of full rank, and deduce that $|\mathcal{A}|\leq n$.

Comment: Yes, you win Sean. Great job!

Comment: Thanks. Wish I could say it's my own.

Comment: Fabulous solution ! Many thanks, Sean.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For a set of length $i > 2$, no other set can have any subset of that set $i \ge 2$ as a subset.